# IndexError: boolean array no longer matching after Python upgrade

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have code running in a for loop.

For each iteration of the loop I find the maximum value for that row of my DataFrame, I then create a list of column indexes where that value appears (because it may sometimes appear more than once) and finally I take the max() of this list to give the highest column index for that row containing the maximum value.

The code I use looks like this:

```
index = 0
for i in df['column']:
    maxValue = df.values[index, :].max()
    peaklist = df.index[df.values[index, :] == maxValue].tolist()
    lastpeak = max(peaklist)
    index += 1
```

After updating my Python (I think this is why), my "peaklist" creation now fails with an IndexError saying "boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 'x' but corresponding boolean dimension is 'y'"

I've looked at other instances of this on the forums and can't seem to find an easy one-line solution to rewrite my code and get the same result that I was previously. Can anyone help?

EDIT

Example DataFrame:

```
0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7

a     100    200    200    150    100    125    200
b
c
d
e
```

For the first iteration in this example, "maxValue" would be equal to 200, the "peaklist" created would be [2, 3, 7] and the "lastpeak" would be equal to 7.

Comment: Not sure what your desired output is - can you share an example `df`, preferably as text, along with the expected output?

Comment: Sure, see the updated post. The output I'm missing is for "peaklist" - it's just a list which contains column indexes where the indexes are for the columns where the maximum value of that row can be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, apparently the numpy tuple method works:

```
peaklist = np.where(df.values[index, :] == maxValue)
lastpeak = max(max(peak))
```

I'm going to leave the question open for a few days in hopes that someone has a better method or an explanation of what the issue actually was.